# WordPress PHP Random Image Script

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been displaying using the below code for a few years to display a random image in WordPress without any issues. The code broke today when I upgraded to PHP 7.4. I'm stuck on how to make the code work again or replace it with new code so that images from a directory are randomly displayed.

*Update: Broken code means images are you no longer being displayed. There are no error messages our outputs, just a blank section where the random image would usually display.

```html
<?php
$folder = '';
$exts = 'jpg jpeg png gif';
$files = array(); $i = -1;
if ('' == $folder) $folder = './';
$handle = opendir($folder);
$exts = explode(' ', $exts);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
foreach($exts as $ext) {
if (preg_match('/\.'.$ext.'$/i', $file, $test)) {
$files[] = $file;
++$i;
}
}
}
closedir($handle);
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$rand = mt_rand(0, $i);
header('Location: '.$folder.$files[$rand]); // Voila!
?>
```

The file is called rotate.php and it's located within the images directory. I call the rotate.php script from within the website's css style sheet using the following code:

```html
background: #ffffff url(images/rotate.php) no-repeat center top;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "The code broke today" -- in what way? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Images are you no longer being displayed. There are no error messages our outputs, just a blank section where the random image would usually display.

Comment: Okay, so what sort of debugging have you done? Is `$files` filled with the expected files? Is `$rand` within the `$files` array bounds? `$folder` appears to be a relative path, does `var_dump(realpath($folder));` point to the correct location? If you set `error_reporting` and `display_errors` to show everything, do you see any warnings or notices?

Comment: Hi Rick, after rolling back to PHP 5.4 the issue still persisted. It appears to be an issue with the latest version of WordPress. I'm not sure, but maybe the latest version of WordPress or the previous version has introduced additional security measures that may be restricting the execution of the php script?

Comment: Rick, all done. Disabled plugins and found the issue. Thanks for your help. Resolved!